# How do I get a range of cells in PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to read some data from an `xls` file.

I want to get a couple of cells at once, say: A6 - A11.

I know I can use `$cell = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getCell('A6');` to get a single cell, and I could probably loop through an array and get each cell in my range.

But, isn't there a simpler method to get a range of cells something like `getCellRange('A6:A11')` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is, the [`rangeToArray()`](http://hitautodestruct.github.io/PHPExcelAPIDocs/classes/PHPExcel_Worksheet.html#method_rangeToArray) method:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->rangeToArray('A1:C3');
```

Wondering why I bother documenting these methods in the first place, but here's the argument list as well:

```
/**
 *  Create array from a range of cells
 *
 *  @param   string    $pRange              Range of cells (i.e. "A1:B10"),
 *                                             or just one cell (i.e. "A1")
 *  @param   mixed     $nullValue           Value returned in the array entry 
 *                                             if a cell doesn't exist
 *  @param   boolean   $calculateFormulas   Should formulas be calculated?
 *  @param   boolean   $formatData          Should formatting be applied to cell values?
 *  @param   boolean   $returnCellRef       False - Return a simple array of rows 
 *                                             and columns indexed by number counting
 *                                             from zero
 *                                         True - Return rows and columns indexed by 
 *                                             their actual row and column IDs
 *  @return array
 */
```

Comment: I actually found this method in the API about 30 minutes after I posted this question. But it was not easy to find :) Still, this is what SO is all about. Thanks!

Comment: I apologise that PHP-Documentor API docs are so hard to use; I'll make sure to chastise Mike van Riel next time I see him

Comment: LOL, it's just missing a decent search feature.. Why isn't it online anywhere?

Comment: All the documents are; the API isn't because neither github nor codeplex support it and I spend more than enough time/money on maintaining PHPExcel anyway to get another host that will

Comment: Would you mind if I hosted it on Amazon S3 or my own server for posterity?

Comment: No problem with that, though it is subject to change with any new releases

Comment: http://hitautodestruct.github.io/PHPExcelAPIDocs/ I will try and keep these up to date.